# Sending explicit zeroes in protobuf3

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

In Protobuf3 zero is the default value for numeric types, and so they are filtered out when serialized.

I have an application where I need to send a value only when it has changed. For example, x was 1, now x is 0, send this value.

It isn't possible to send only the delta, eg -1, because some of these values are floats or doubles, and we do not want to accrue errors.

There are over 200 different variables in some classes I need to serialize, so solutions like "add a boolean to flag which fields have changed" are possible but not fun. Other suggestions that have a large amount of per-field work or processing are undesirable too.

Is there a simple mechanism to tell protobuf3 to explicitly keep a value even though it is the default value?

Possible solutions:

- Send the entire class each time. The main downside here is some fields may have a lot of data.
- Use a boolean "has changed" in the schema to indicate if a variable has changed, even if it is 0
- Use a magic value. Terrible idea, but possible. Not going to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to distinguish `0` and `null` then you can use proto3 wrapper types: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp-generated#wrapper_types
There are special wrapper types for such case: [`StringWrapper`, `Int32Wrapper` and etc](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto). All of the wrapper types that correspond to C# value types (`Int32Wrapper, DoubleWrapper, BoolWrapper` etc) are mapped to `Nullable<T>` where `T` is the corresponding non-nullable type.

Comment: This is basically what I have working at the moment, mapping the class to a message class with nullable. While not super clean, it's definitely a lot cleaner than alternate solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged [protobuf-net](/questions/tagged/protobuf-net), you can do this at the field level:

```cs
[ProtoMember(..., IsRequired = true)]
// your field
```

or globally (here I'm assuming you are using the default model, which is a pretty safe assumption usually):

```cs
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.ImplicitZeroDefault = false;
```

and you're done;

---

Note: if you're interested in deltas, you can also do this *conditionally* - for a property `Foo`, you can add:

```cs
private bool ShouldSerializeFoo() { /* your rules here */ }
```

(this is a name-based pattern used by many serializers and other tools; in some scenarios, it needs to be `public`, but protobuf-net is usually happy with it non-public)

---

As a non-trivial example of an object that tracks delta state internally:

```cs
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new MyType
        {
            Foo = 42,
            Bar = "abc",
            Blap = DateTime.Now
        };
        ShowPayloadSize("original", obj);
        obj.MarkClean();
        ShowPayloadSize("clean", obj);

        obj.Foo = 42;
        obj.Bar = "abc";
        ShowPayloadSize("set property to same", obj);

        obj.Foo = 45;
        obj.Bar = "new value";
        ShowPayloadSize("set property to different", obj);

        obj.MarkClean();
        ShowPayloadSize("clean again", obj);
    }
    static void ShowPayloadSize<T>(string caption, T obj)
    {
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer.Serialize(ms, obj);
        Console.WriteLine($"{caption}: {ms.Length} bytes");
    }
}


[ProtoContract]
public class MyType
{


    private int _dirty = -1; // treat everything as dirty by default
    public void MarkClean() => _dirty = 0;
    public bool IsDirty => _dirty != 0;

    private bool ShouldSerialize(int flag) => (_dirty & flag) != 0;

    private void Set<T>(ref T field, T value, int flag)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            _dirty |= flag;
        }
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Foo
    {
        get => _foo;
        set => Set(ref _foo, value, 1 << 0);
    }
    public bool ShouldSerializeFoo() => ShouldSerialize(1 << 0);
    private int _foo;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Bar
    {
        get => _bar;
        set => Set(ref _bar, value, 1 << 1);
    }
    public bool ShouldSerializeBar() => ShouldSerialize(1 << 1);
    private string _bar;

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public DateTime Blap
    {
        get => _blap;
        set => Set(ref _blap, value, 1 << 2);
    }
    public bool ShouldSerializeBlap() => ShouldSerialize(1 << 2);
    private DateTime _blap;
}
```

Comment: Some solid suggestions there Marc. Would you be able to give me a solid example? Foo has an attribute x that I want to serialize only if it changes. How would that interact with ShouldSerializeFoo? I have two Foo objects, foo1, and foo2, and changed variables are located using if (foo1.x != foo2.x)

Comment: @gszavae any change tracking needs to be implemented in *your* code; that isn't something that the library provides. However! You might also get some joy out of `Nullable<T>` i.e. an `int? Foo` won't serialize if it is `null`, but will serialize if it is a non-`null` value.

Comment: that's a bit of a dangerous solution, but it would work! I am not sure how I would implement the change tracking as per your suggested use of ShouldSerializeFoo.

Comment: @gszavae see edit for a possible way of implementing that

Comment: Thanks for the example. I wish there was a solution that didn't require such a volume of changes, but I think this is a great solution. My only concern is the bitshifting. Ints only have 4 bytes, even a long only has 8 bytes. I don't think 1 << 200 is going to work out well! Another solution for tracking changes will be needed.

Comment: One part I'm not clear on is how deserializing works. I can see that a default value has been written (eg Foo = 0) however I am not aware of how I can detect this when deserializing the value. Normally I would use Serializer.Deserialize<MyType>, but I'm not seeing how this will help me distinguish between implied 0 and explicit 0. Even if I manually check the protobuf.Foo it still isn't clear to me how I can check if something was serialized or not. I appreciate the assistance by the way, sorry if my original question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @gszavae if you have > 64 fields: just use multiple masks - one per 64

Comment: @gszavae in *that* scenario (detecting implicit vs explicit zero); you could perhaps use an `[OnBeforeDeserialize]` that sets the masks to zero, and then after deserialization: anything that is set (in the masks): was present. The only slight gotcha there is that *currently* the `Set<T>` method there doesn't set the mask when the values match, but: reserve a bit in the mask for "is currently deserializing", and change it to "if deserializing *or* the value is different, set the mask" - if you see what I mean. Your scenario is ... not typical, so: you may have to write a few lines of code here.