# How to find "delta" or "diff" between 2 objects using protobuf.net, to track have been changed

Tags: c#, serialization, synchronization, protobuf-net

I know the question is rather vague, but lets say I have the 2 objects

```
Object A
{
  Id: 1,
  Title: "Abc",
  Flag: true
}

Object B
{
  Id: 1,
  Title: "",
  Flag: false
}
```

Is there a way in to find what got changed? Knowing that the title was set to "" (or null is ok) and the Flag was set to false.

All my object are currently serialized with protobuf.net (C#) and I would like to know if there is a "magic" way to do that. The objects have 100+ properties so I would like a way to do not it one by one.

Can we enumerate all properties grammatically and store that in a generic container?

The code is used in a context of synchronizing objects from concurrent users.

Thanks

Comment: I think it should be possible in principle, but I have no idea how. But what output would you expect? consider that an objects might contain other objects or list of objects. So specifying what property on what object is different might might be a bit complex.

Comment: Short answer is "yes, that is possible". Long answer will need to wait until I'm at my PC. Context: author of protobuf-net

Comment: @JonasH it's a good question, I'm up to anything that would work including an array of "property" : "value".
MarcGravell I know who you are, thanks a lots for looking into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protobuf-net itself does not track differences - that simply isn't a feature (it has no "context" wrapper to store the before/after state). However, *your type can*, if it likes, and protobuf-net is able to use "conditional serialization" to only transmit deltas. This is *effectively* a re-statement of [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61931373/23354), which includes a code example of doing this.

Comment: I have issue with the 0, false, null that are not serialized as stated in my example. Is the RuntimeTypeModel.Default.ImplicitZeroDefault = false; doing the trick? Does that would affect the rest of my code doing serialization?

Comment: @Zyo yes, that's implicit zeros at work (which is what proto3 wants, note); I can't remember without checking, but conditional serialization *might* override that; if you change it on the default model (if you *can* change it on the default model), then: everything that uses the default model will be impacted. You can have multiple models, though, and use a different model with implicit zeros disabled for this bit.

Comment: I like the fact 0, null, "", [ ] are not serialized at all. In 99% of the time it's what we want, smaller data to transfer, save and load. I don't wanna break this. I want to know diff between 2 objects not really difference between 0 and null.

Comment: @Zyo that isn't a feature that is relevant to this library, so: that's something you'd need to do your own way. I've linked you to a mechanism for tracking simple changes - whether it does what you want is another matter.