# Protobuf-net pattern for optionally assignable nullable types (not collections)

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have been searching for a while, and have found the various threads indicating that protobuf-net can handle nullable types, the various threads about things like empty collections (not relevant here), and the default value behaviour for what would previously have been "optional" fields in proto2, but I have not found a specific answer to the following question. This will be my first time using protobuf-net, or protocol buffers as a serialization format.

Imagine I am sending messages between multiple different applications using an event carried state transfer pattern - so publishers and subscribers of messages containing state - and some kind of shared model for that state. Any participating applications have some representation of "the same" entity (hence the ECST), but not all systems understand all attributes. In terms of persistence in the applications' SQL database, that might look like this (scales left off for brevity):

```
table App1Products { productKey int, productName varchar null }

table App2Products { productKey int, productName varchar null, productWeightKg decimal null }

table App3Products { productKey int }
```

For the sake of the example, suppose the trivial shared model is the union of all of the distinct attributes: `{ productKey, productName, productWeightKg }`

Now suppose someone updates a `productName` in `App1Products`. We want to publish that changed state. When we do this we can't populate the entire shared model, because App1 does not include the `productWeightKg` in its schema. We need to somehow "leave out" any value for this element in a way that potential consumers understand that it was not populated.

We can't merely send a default value (0) (or let subscribers deserialize a missing element to a default value) to convey "no update" semantics, because that would cause the `productWeightKg` value to be set to 0 in the `App2Products` table when the message is received by App2. We can't send null to convey "no update" semantics, because null is a legitimate value for the column as well.

Ultimately, we need the subscriber code at App2 to construct an update statement such that either the `productWeightKg` column is not referenced, or it is simply set to itself, and we need some way of telling App2's subscriber code to do that.

One solution seems to be to create an additional element in the message for each field, indicating whether the field is or is not set. In terms of the message content, we might use something like this:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class Product
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int ProductKey { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string productName { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public decimal? productWeightKg { get; private set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public bool productWeightKgSet { get; private set; }

    public void SetProductWeight(decimal? weight)
    {
        productWeightKg = weight;
        productWeightKgSet = true;
    }

    public void ClearProductWeight()
    {
        productWeightKgSet = false;
    }
}
```

If that is a reasonable sort of pattern to use, then the next "obvious" idea would be to create some kind of template class for this sort of behaviour which we can reuse for all of our message classes...

```cs
public class Optional<T>
{
    public T Value { get; private set; }
    public bool HasValue { get; private set; }

    public void Set(T val) { Value = val; HasValue = true; }
    public void Clear() { HasValue = false; Value = default; }
}
```

Is this a reasonable sort of approach to solving this problem, or is there some other "known good pattern" that I've missed, or something about this pattern which won't work as expected with protobuf-net?

My limited understanding at the moment is that this might require that the Optional class be decorated with all of its possible child implementations using the ProtoInclude attribute, is that correct?

Comment: It sounds like you're taking about "conditional serialization" combined with "merge" (rather than deserialize) - the answer here covers a lot of similar territory - any use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61931285/sending-explicit-zeroes-in-protobuf3/61931373#61931373

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, there are similar ideas there in terms of deltas. I expressed a point to point message, but the context here is pub/sub through a broker and a common data model which all of App1...AppN can use to share state without knowing about each other explicitly. A trivial common model would be the union of all semantically distinct attributes across all systems. Any single publisher may not be able to populate the entire shared model, but any subscriber needs to know which fields were not populated by the publisher so that they are not treated as "real" changes (eg, to null).

Comment: As I understand that linked thread, I can see that the potentially useful idea is to have each message contain a single bitmask representing all fields with some per-field way to read the mask, rather than a solution where each "real" field contains its own companion bool. This removes the need for the Optional<T> as the fundamental type of any element in the message, which seems like it would help in terms of a protobuf-net implementation, removing inheritance and nesting, although it does require more care when adding new fields.

Comment: I have updated the question to better reflect the pub/sub common model state transfer semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, the intention of protobuf-net is not to provide a robust field-tracking mechanism, and since it works against POCO types - it has nowhere to *store* any additional state, except that which your object model provides. It *does* support considitonal serialization, and there are many things that *your model* can do to track changes internally, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61931285/sending-explicit-zeroes-in-protobuf3/61931373#61931373); this may be useful in combintion with `Merge` (rather than deserialization) - but going beyond that isn't something provided out-of-the-box (it also isn't provided by most other POCO serializers, as far as I know).

There *is* some crossover between what you describe and the [`FieldMask`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/field-mask) concept, but: to date, protobuf-net has not has a need to implement or support `FieldMask`.

I'm always happy to explore new things that the library might be able to do to help people, but if there is a missing library feature: this is probably something better discussed on GitHub, along with very specific  details of the target scenario and motivations, etc.

Comment: Yep, this is indeed is a question about how I should write my code which makes use of a protobuf-net serialization for transmission, not so much a question about the features provided by protobuf-net.

Some models which provide explicit "value not set by publisher" style semantics might be an easier fit with protobuf-net than others. My example solution requires serialization of a generic (which seems fine, but maybe there are gotchas), and inheritance of the serialized type (which has some administrative overhead), and so on. So it's a question about patterns incorporating protobuf-net.

Comment: @allmhuran so yes; protobuf-net has the pieces to put that together, but it doesn't do the tracking itself